# TensorFlow 2.1 failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, python-3.7, tensorflow2.0

I am a beginner TensorFlow user and am running into the following issue when attempting to load an already saved model.

I am following along with this tutorial: https://youtu.be/6g4O5UOH304?t=7532

When running the code at that point in the video, I am greeted with this error:

```
2020-02-03 08:59:24.589058: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2020-02-03 08:59:24.589234: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/btu/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/venv/testMovieReviews.py", line 53, in <module>
    encode = review_encode(nline)
  File "C:/Users/btu/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/venv/testMovieReviews.py", line 41, in review_encode
    encoded.append(word_index[word])
KeyError: 'Of'
```

TF Version: TensorFlow 2.1

OS: Windows 10

CPU: Intel Core i7-2600 CPU (From what I have searched, it supports AVX)

GPU: AMD RADEON HD 6450

Language: Python 3.7

IDE: Pycharm 2019.3.1

I am confused, as prior threads to this error seem to appear for Nvidia graphics cards, but I am not running one.

Answer (score 1):

I also meet the same error as yours on my PC(win 10), but my program can keep running.

So, your problem here is not "failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)", it seems it's your code has some KeyError. You should check your code firstly.

Simple example:

```
    tf> python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"

    2020-04-29 09:22:01.959213: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found

    2020-04-29 09:22:01.962833: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

    2020-04-29 09:22:09.075191: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found

    2020-04-29 09:22:09.079202: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
    .....

   tf.Tensor(-101.936615, shape=(), dtype=float32)    <=== This is the output and ignore the previous error info
```

Moreover, please refer to [here](https://forum.rasa.com/t/tensorflow-driver-unknown-error-303/21661) for more details.